# Must the IUnknown interface be re-implemented by every new COM class?

Tags: c++, com, iunknown

Sorry if this question seems obvious for everyone, but I am very new to COM. From the tutorial I see here http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567, it seems like every COM class created in C++ must implement its own QueryInterface, AddRef and Release. Since these methods should have basically the same implementation for any new class, I don't understand why there isn't some abstract class or whatever that implements it for the developer. I don't understand why I should re-implement the same thing that so many people have already implemented again and again (unless the tutorial is wrong and there IS something).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTA:

> "I believe that every programmer who wishes to understand the basic principles behind COM, must write atleast one simple COM object using plain C++ , i.e. without the aid of templates and macros that comes along with MFC/ATL."

To answer your question: Yes, every COM component must implement [IUnknown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUnknown), it's the foundation COM is built on. However, as for the "standard pluming" for creating COM objects this is what the [ATL Project Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd845614%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is for.

Comment: This wizard is quite useless. When I try it, it tells me it is going to add ATL support to my project, and then I get a fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file "MyResource.h. My project compiles fine, and the MyResource.h file exists and it is the include path.

Comment: But anyway you answered the question, I forgot I had read that at the beginning of the tutorial sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @Carl Not a stupid question, everyone on earth has "duh" moments (these come exponentially when working with COM I've found). Good luck your project.

Comment: @Carl: You resolve that RC1015 by editing the resource compiler settings - they are in Configuration->Resources->General and you have to alter the include path.

Comment: @sharptooth: Yeah I had already done that, my project wouldn't compile if not. But when I run the wizard it gives me RC1015, then I check the project settings and my resource include paths are removed. So I re-write them, but every time I run the wizard they are removed, don't know why -_-...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use ATL or other helper libraries you can use the [QISearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helper function that handles QueryInterface for you. AddRef and Release can be implemented in your own base class.

COM needs to work with plain C also so the windows sdk does not really go beyond the definition of the class and its methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every COM class must implement `IUnknown`, because every COM class inherits from `IUnknown` - that's one of the basic COM technology principles. This is usually done by using ATL - it has templates and macros for doing that rather easily and even if you don't want to use ATL you can write a template for most trivial cases (like implementing one interface) pretty easily and reuse that.