# How do I re-use an interface implementation in many classes?

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class, reusability

This question could also have been entitled "How to do reference-counting without ATL".  Some similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6507372/98903) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10779834/98903), but in the former a different question was answered and in both cases, ATL is involved.  My question is more general to C++ and not so much about COM.

Suppose we have an `IUnknown` "interface", like so:

```
class IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual ULONG AddRef() = 0;
    virtual ULONG Release() = 0;
    virtual ULONG QueryInterface(void * iid, void **ppv) = 0;
};
```

...and let's throw in a few other interfaces that are part of a fictional SDK:

```
class IAnimal : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual IAnimal** GetParents() = 0;
};

class IMammal : public IAnimal
{
public:
    virtual ULONG Reproduce() = 0;
};
```

Since I am going to be implementing several animals and mammals, I would rather not copy-paste the `AddRef()` and `Release()` implementations in every class, so I wrote `UnknownBase`:

```
class UnknownBase : public IUnknown
{
public:
    UnknownBase()
    {
        _referenceCount = 0;
    }
    ULONG AddRef()
    {
        return ++_referenceCount;
    }
    ULONG Release()
    {
        ULONG result = --_referenceCount;
        if (result == 0)
        {
            delete this;
        }
        return result;
    }
private:
    ULONG _referenceCount;
};
```

...so that I may use it to, say, implement a `Cat`:

```
class Cat : public IMammal, UnknownBase
{
public:
    ULONG QueryInterface(void *, void**);

    IAnimal** GetParents();
    ULONG Reproduce();
};

ULONG Cat::QueryInterface(void * iid, void **ppv)
{
    // TODO: implement
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

IAnimal** Cat::GetParents()
{
    // TODO: implement
    return NULL;
}

ULONG Cat::Reproduce()
{
    // TODO: implement
    return 0;
}
```

...however, the compiler disagrees:

```
c:\path\to\farm.cpp(42): error C2259: 'Cat' : cannot instantiate abstract class
          due to following members:
          'ULONG IUnknown::AddRef(void)' : is abstract
          c:\path\to\iunknown.h(8) : see declaration of 'IUnknown::AddRef'
          'ULONG IUnknown::Release(void)' : is abstract
          c:\path\to\iunknown.h(9) : see declaration of 'IUnknown::Release'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Side note - If your `unknownbase` is only present to provide an impl to those two functions and your original interface is only used through it, you can consider moving the impl directly into the interface itself.

Comment: Ah, that would be easier, but in this case I don't control `IUnknown` or any of the other interfaces.  I'm merely implementing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not require changing the interface definitions:

```
template<class I>
class UnknownBase : public I
{
    ...
}

class Cat : public UnknownBase<IMammal>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is called the curiously recurring template pattern: CRTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class template that allows you to specify the base class as a template argument. This will eliminate the need to implement a final override function in the derived class.

You also need to make sure that you declare the member functions with the correct calling convention, return type and parameter types.

```
template<typename Base>
class UnknownImpl : public Base
{
public:

    UnknownImpl() : _referenceCount(0)
    {
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_referenceCount);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
    {
        ULONG result = InterlockedDecrement(&_referenceCount);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            delete this;
        }
        return result;
    }

private:

    ULONG _referenceCount;
};


class Cat : public UnknownImpl<IMammal>
{
public:
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID, void**);

    IAnimal** GetParents();
    ULONG Reproduce();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that I should probably be using `Interlocked[In|De]crement`.

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit using [virtual base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class).  Change:

class IAnimal : public IUnknown --> class IAnimal : public virtual IUnknown;  and

class UnknownBase : public IUnknown --> class UnknownBase : public virtual IUnknown

Comment: That only works if I can control the definition of `IAnimal`, but I can not.